# Custom JavaScript alerts in iOS using PhoneGap HTML

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova

My app has a couple of JS alerts and it seems to always display the page name like.

index.html

Is there a way to change the index.html to my App's name or custom text.

Example:

```
My App // Which replaces .index.html
alert("I am an alert box!");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Simon said check out the notifications it's part of the phonegap API.

You call it like this -

Notification with options:

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
   "This is my Alert text!",
    callBackFunction, // Specify a function to be called 
    'Alert Title',
    ["Ok", "Awesome"]
);

function callBackFunction(b){
  if(b == 1){
    console.log("user said ok");
  }
  else {
    console.log("user said Awesome");
  }
}
```

A simple notification -

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    "This is my Alert text!",
    callBackFunctionB, // Specify a function to be called 
    'Alert Title',
    "OK"
);
function callBackFunctionB(){
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not showing anything, I tried by installing  cordova-plugin-vibration and cordova-plugin-dialogs plugins for ios Application, any idea..?!

Comment: My cordova app uses location services, so iOS throws a default alert for user persmission which has app directory..index.html. How to fix this?

Answer (score 15):

To be able to test on both a desktop browser and PhoneGap application, I suggest to use a dynamic approach as such:

```
function showMessage(message, callback, title, buttonName) {

    title = title || "default title";
    buttonName = buttonName || 'OK';

    if(navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {

        navigator.notification.alert(
            message,    // message
            callback,   // callback
            title,      // title
            buttonName  // buttonName
        );

    } else {

        alert(message);
        callback();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, supports BOTH desktop and PhoneGap!

Comment: Glad you found it useful @JOM!

Comment: Actually instead of `invoke(callback)` should be `callback()`. Otherwise you get error invoke is not defined

Comment: That's correct @igo, invoke is actually a reusable method that I wrote somewhere else that only invokes callback if it's defined.

Answer (score 2):

Use [navigator.notfication.alert](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert) as you can provide your own title.