# JQuery - Using navigator.notification.alert

Tags: jquery-mobile, notifications, cordova, customization, alert

I have a requirement for a popup to appear with a custom heading (having it appear from index.html on an app just looks tacky).

I tried the suggestion at the end of the following link:

[Custom JavaScript alerts in iOS using PhoneGap HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432615/custom-javascript-alerts-in-ios-using-phonegap-html)

So I added the code below to my index.html in the script section:

```
   function showMessage(message, callback, title, buttonName){

        title = title || "default title";
        buttonName = buttonName || 'OK';

        if(navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert){

            navigator.notification.alert(
                message,    // message
                callback,   // callback
                title,      // title
                buttonName  // buttonName
            );

        }else{

            alert(message);
            callback();
        }

    }
```

UPDATE

I have the following code for the alert;

```
if ((inputNumber>maxAllowed))
        {
        showMessage("The input is too high.",null,"Warning","Warning");
        }
```

After compiling the app, this is not working.

The following is in index.html:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
            }

<function shown above is here>
```

Any idea why this is still not working? Showing from index.html

Thank you.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

Comment: The phonegap methos will not work in a browser, they use native resources. Your code seems fine thought. Run it on a phone and you should see your notification.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I need to compile the app with the new code then? i.e. I can't use xcode?

Comment: Not sure if i follow your question. If you want to try it on a mac follow the phonegap instructions for creating an iOS app and add your own html code instead of the example. Yes, you can use xcode. You just can't run it on chrome, or firefox, or any browser, you have to run it as an app on a phone/emulator.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, was asking if I can run from browser on iPhone simulator (xCode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error tells you that function **`navigator.notification`** don't exist.

Usually this is because:

1. Phonegap/Cordova is not initialized inside a HEAD
2. Function is not initialized inside a deviceready event. Basically function can't be called before cordova.js is fully initialized.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
       // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Gajotres, I am using this on the browser so Phonegap and Cordova won't have been initialised. I think I may have misunderstood the original thread - I thought that his code would allow the custom alert to appear even when using a browser

Comment: navigator.notification will work only if cordova.js is included and only on mobile devices. That's why original post checks if it exist before using it. Also this function will work only on mobile devices, you can use Cordova.js created for desktop browsers but I think it don't have notification function.

Comment: Basically if you want to use cordova functionalities it must be initialized. Not to mention appropriate version must be initialized, iOS version will not work on windows and vice versa.

Comment: Ah thank you. I'll recompile the app as soon as I can (just trying to figure out how to get a certain screen on landscape only). Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, this isn't actually working. I compiled the new app but notifications are still showing from index.html. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function I use while testing Phonegap applications on my PC. I remove it when deploying app on mobile device. It's for confirm function, but you can adjust it for alerting and so on.

```
    // TODO: remove on deploy
    navigator.notification = {
        confirm: function (message, successCallback) {
            successCallback(1);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing in a browser so `navigator.notification` is undefined. Also It seems that you added the function `showMessage` but you are not using it. Try with:

```
showMessage("The value is too high!", null,"Warning", "Warning");
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, using showMessage works but it still says "localhost" as the from (it is using the else part of the defined function).

Comment: @Gary "localhost"? What do you mean? And you cannot use phonegap functions from a desktop/regular browser...

Comment: Aye, that's my mistake. Will recompile this as an app and test. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Johnathon, I've tried the above in my phonegap compiled app and it is not working. I updated above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From phone, notice that the callback is not a string.  So in your function, you pass it a string and that is causing it a problem.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

I see this is the case because I am trying to do this also. So unfortunately you cannot override the callback, and you need to "hard Code" it.

Answer (score 0):

I have add the plugin using CLI like :

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

and its working fine for me.