# Error: Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, types, cordova-plugins

I'm attempting to use the ionic plugin `cordova-plugin-dialogs`, the plugin is working and I am able to call `navigator.notification.alert()` and create a native alert prompt but whenever my app builds, I get the following console error:

> error TS2339: Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

I read online that this could be related to types but I have confirmed that the types for this plugin are installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - Using navigator.notification.alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470202/jquery-using-navigator-notification-alert)

Comment: If this is a typescript error, then something is fishy with the installed types for the plugin. Do you have the .d.ts file? If so is it contains the navigator class/interface with the notification class/interface?

Comment: @scipper definitively not a duplicate of your linked question... 

Comment: Was you able to solve the problem @joe-scotto?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved was to add this to my typings.json:

```
    "dialogs": "github:apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/types/index.d.ts"
```

My project is old and still use typings. I use grunt to build, so I instal the typings.