# Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator' on Cordova + VueJS + Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

App.vue is my main layout file. It has the navigation and lots of other stuff.

```
<template>
  <div 
    id="app" 
    role="main"
  >
...
  <router-view />
...


<script lang="ts">
...

import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {


...

    onResume():any  {
      setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.notification.alert("Device has resumed!", null, "Message", "OK")
        navigator.notification.beep(2)

      }, 0)
    }

...

  mounted() {

    document.addEventListener("resume", this.onResume)
  }

...
</script>
```

**Config**

In `src-cordova/package.json`,  have

```
...
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {}
    },
...
```

** When Compiling **

```
When I `npm run cordova-build-browser`


461:19 Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
    459 |     onResume():any  {
    460 |       setTimeout(function() {
  > 461 |         navigator.notification.alert("Device has resumed!", null, "Message", "OK")
        |                   ^
    462 |         navigator.notification.beep(2)
    463 | 
    464 |         this.$store.dispatch("upcoming")
```

I get a similar error message for beep

** I have considered **

```
npm run cordova-serve-browser
```

This runs fine. I still need to build browser

I have tried this

[Error: Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732082/error-property-notification-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator)

But this mentions a typings file. And I understand that `typings.json` is obsolete

I have tried

```
    (navigator as any).notification.alert("Device has resumed!", null, "Message", "OK")
    (navigator as any).notification.beep(2)
```

But I just get

```
   462:9  error  Unexpected newline between function and ( of function call  no-unexpected-multiline
```