# JQuery + PhoneGap - Custom Notification Alerts

Tags: jquery, notifications, cordova, phonegap-build, alerts

I've been spending some time trying to find out why I can't get my custom notifications on my app to work.

Below is the code in my .js:

```
if (inputOne > maxAllowed)
{
     showMessage("Your Input is too high.",null,"Warning","Warning");
}
```

Below is the code in my .html:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
      // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}

function showMessage(message, callback, title, buttonName) {

    title = title || "Warning!";
    buttonName = buttonName || 'Warning!';

    if(navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert) {

          navigator.notification.alert(
                message,    // message
                callback,   // callback
                title,      // title
                buttonName  // buttonName
           );

     } else {
          alert(message);
     }
```

In my config.xml for PhoneGap I have:

Below is the link I was using to get this:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

What happens is, it just uses the `else` part and works normally.

The .html is from the below link:

[Custom JavaScript alerts in iOS using PhoneGap HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432615/custom-javascript-alerts-in-ios-using-phonegap-html)

Any ideas please?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

Comment: Where is the top snippet located in your code relatively to the bottom snippet?

Comment: they are in two different files. the showMessage is in my javascript file (calculations.js) along with all the math behind the app. the function() part is in the index.html in the script tags <>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else seeing this issue, you need to add the following in the index.html:

```
<!-- Add PhoneGap library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Good luck!